# UINavigationBar + UIToolBar UIAppearance as well as translucent barStyle in some parts of the app?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uitoolbar, uiappearance

I am setting custom images for my `UINavigationBar` and `UIToolbar` using the following code:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationBar"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"toolbar"] forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

I am using [PhotoViewer](https://github.com/enormego/PhotoViewer) and pushing its view controller into view. It should have a translucent navigationbar and toolbar, but instead it uses the graphics I have supplied with translucency.

The problem is that later when I push in another view controller (after popping back to super from the PhotoViewer) its toolbar is also translucent which means the content sits behind it.

I have tried the following without luck:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[EGOPhotoViewController class], nil] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[EGOPhotoViewController class], nil] setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UIToolbar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[EGOPhotoViewController class], nil] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
[[UIToolbar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[EGOPhotoViewController class], nil] setBackgroundImage:nil forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Any ideas how I can achieve a black translucent barStyle *just* for the PhotoViewer and keep everything else with my custom graphics?

**UPDATE:** In an attempt to get some help, I've put together a sample project with a custom graphic for the navigation bar and then trying to display a pushed view controller with a translucent navigation bar without success when using the appearance proxy: [EXAMPLE PROJECT](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/5445727/UIAppearanceTest.zip)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've downloaded your sample project and managed to fix it. I'll explain what the problem is.

First of all, the UINavigationBar is contained inside the UINavigationController. So, the RootViewController and the TranslucentViewController are using the same UINavigationBar instance. Perhaps this causes confusion. Also, that's probably why the +appearanceWhenContainedIn: is not working as you expect.

To set the background image of your navigation bars throughout your whole application, you should use +appearance. To set the background image of a single navigation bar in a navigation controller, use -setBackgroundImagE:forBarMetrics: of the UINavigationBar.

The code: in -TranslucentViewController viewWillAppear: set the background image and the bar style. In RootViewController, set the background image and the bar style again. In my experience it's the best to change the navigation bar in -viewWillAppear: instead of -in viewWillDisappear: (or you need to keep track of what to change it back to.)

In RootViewController

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"orangeNavigationBar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

In TranslucentViewController

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
}
```

Oh and: only change it in these place. Not when pushing the view controller or anything.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether or not you use a tabbar too, you can designate your appDelegate as the delegate of the navigation bar, or subclass UINavigationController, so your code becomes aware of all changes to the viewController stack. Then, you set the property on the UINavigationBar to make it transparent or non-transparent depending on the class of the visible viewController.

Comment: I am using a `UITabBarController` unfortunately.

Comment: Well, its not all that bad. The tabBarController becomes the delegate of the UINavigation bars, and you cannot change that. But you can subclass UINavigation bar (I did for different reasons), and add methods (which also call super!) to intercept changes to the viewControllers. Its not that hard, and you can set the transparency of the tabBarController as you want as each viewController is the currently viewed one.

Comment: I thought for sure UIAppearance would have some way of dealing with this? I mean Apple seems to be doing it just fine in the Music.app.

Comment: Why do you assume that they achieve this result with UIAppearance? If the problem is ONLY when you come back from pushing a PhotoViewer, then set a flag, and when you get a viewWillAppear message, look at the flag, and set the nab bar translucency. Or just check it everywhere in viewWillAppear and set it as you want it.

Comment: I've checked the code and it's being set back to the original style on `viewWillDisappear` in the PhotoViewer view controller. I've also tried to set it to default on the super view controller as well as the view controller I am pushing after the PhotoViewer, and it does not work. Besides, I am not even seeing the *default* black translucent style, but instead my own graphics for the navigation bar and toolbar with some translucency - which is not the effect I am looking for.